# Hessian matrix at non-stationary point

Tags: calculus

For a 2-variable function $f(x,y)$, by *Taylor* expansion, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y) &\approx& f|_{(0,0)} + f_x'|_{(0,0)}x + f_y'|_{(0,0)}y + \frac{1}{2}\left(f_{xx}''|_{(0,0)}x^2 + f_{yy}''|_{(0,0)}y^2 + 2f_{xy}''|_{(0,0)}xy\right)\\&\approx& f|_{(0,0)} + J^Tw + \frac{1}{2}w^T\mathcal{H}w
\end{eqnarray*}
, while
$$w=\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array}\right),\ J=\left(\begin{array}{c} f_x'|_{(0,0)} \\ f_y'|_{(0,0)}\end{array}\right),\ \mathcal{H}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}f_{xx}''|_{(0,0)} & f_{xy}''|_{(0,0)} \\f_{xy}''|_{(0,0)} & f_{yy}''|_{(0,0)}\end{array}\right)$$
, and I know that the quadratic term $\mathcal{H}$ in the above equation is Hessian matrix.

If $J=0$, which means $(0,0)$ is a stationary point, then
$$f(x,y) \approx f|_{(0,0)} + \frac{1}{2}w^T\mathcal{H}w$$
, and **just for $J=0$**, I can understand that **the eigenvectors of $\mathcal{H}$ determines the value of  $f(x,y)$**.

But what if $(0,0)$ is not a stationary point, which means $J \ne 0$, will $\mathcal{H}$ still determine the value of $f(x,y)$ change? I'm not sure, since **$J$ will have some influence**, right?

To clarify, I think the eigenvalues determines how $f$ changes in a given direction from $(0,0)$, right?

Answer (score 1):

As Evan noted, when the differential $J$ is non-zero the behaviour of $f$ is dominated by the linear approximation $f(0) + Jw$ for small $w$. The next-order deviation from this linear function ($f(w) - f(0) - Jw$) is what the quadratic term $H$ determines. That is, **the eigenvectors of $H$ approximately determine the value of $f(w) - f(0) - Jw$**.

One way to think about it is in terms of curvature: the base value $f(0)$ and the linear term $Jw$ determine a function whose graph is a plane, which is then "curved" by higher order terms, of which $w^T H w$ is the most significant for small $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The J first order term will dominate the quadratic Hessian term for small $x,y$. A simple illustration is to look at the analogous situation for one dimension. In general $x^2$ decays faster than $x$ for $x$ tending to zero, which is why often you will see

$f(x) = f(0)+Jx +O(|x|^2)$

to say that the last term is insignificant compared to the linear term for small x. Here $x$ is a two dimensional vector. To bound the Hessian term by $C|x|^2$, Cauchy Schwarz will do the trick.